# elasticsearch wildcard search java

Tags: java, json, http, elasticsearch-java-api

I am using java low level **REST client api**. 
I am fetching particular fields on matching or related datas from **elasticsearch** by using **wildcards**. 
I am struck with it getting data as well as searching data with **wildcard**. 
How to fetch result in java list .

Here is my code:

```
HttpEntity entity1 = new NStringEntity( "{\n" + " \"query\" : {\n" + " \"wildcard\": { \"Content\":\"java *\"} \n" + "} \n"+ "}",ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON);
Response response = restClient.performRequest("GET", "/test/_search",Collections.singletonMap("pretty", "true"), entity1);
    System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(response.getEnti‌​ty()));
```

Could you please help me out? Thank you!

Comment: Do you have some samples of what you have done so far?

Comment: HttpEntity entity1 = new NStringEntity(
     "{\n" +
    "    \"query\" : {\n" +
    "    \"wildcard\": { \"Content\":\"java *\"} \n" +
    "} \n"+
    "}", ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON);
                                                                   
    Response response = restClient.performRequest("GET", "/test/_search",Collections.singletonMap("pretty", "true"),
                                                               entity1);
    System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()));
But it return empty.. I have values related to java

Comment: adding your code to the post